# Umbraco Form issue

Tags: c#, sql, .net, umbraco, umbraco-contour

When I try to check umbraco form using umbraco back end it gave me the following error:

> Server error: Contact administrator, see log for full details. Failed
>   to retrieve data for child nodes undefined

This is occurring in server and working fine in local development version.

[image]

Comment: What does the log file say? Can you post the error?

Comment: Did you upload all used files to your live server?

Comment: ERROR Umbraco.Core.Security.AuthenticationExtensions - The current identity cannot be converted to Umbraco.Core.Security.UmbracoBackOfficeIdentity
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a Umbraco.Core.Security.UmbracoBackOfficeIdentity from System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity since the required claim http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier is missing
   at Umbraco.Core.Security.UmbracoBackOfficeIdentity.FromClaimsIdentity(ClaimsIdentity identity)

Comment: at Umbraco.Core.Security.AuthenticationExtensions.GetCurrentIdentity(HttpContextBase http, Boolean authenticateRequestIfNotFound)

Comment: above part from error log and I uploaded all related files